# Display the number of published posts for each custom taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy, count

I do have a custom taxonomy called "countries". How do I get each term (country) with the number of its published posts in brackets, like the following:

- Uruguay (3)
- Chile (5)
- Thailand (2)
- etc.

With following code the number of all terms in the "countries" taxonomy is displayed:

```
$countries_count = wp_count_terms( 'countries' );
echo $countries_count;
```

But I just know that this is just a starting point of my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't test this right now but try getting all the terms for "country" and then loop through them and get the wp_count_terms for each of them.
`$terms = get_terms("countries");
     if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
         echo "<ul>";
         foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$args = array(
   'slug'          => $term->slug, 
); 

           echo "<li>" . $term->name . "(" . wp_count_terms('countries', $args) . ")</li>";
        
         }
         echo "</ul>";
     }'

Comment: @leromt : Please don't post large blocks of code in the comments. If you think you have an answer, post it in the answer box.

Comment: @s_ha_dum:  Sorry, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to get the list of all terms associated with a taxonomy. Once you have all the separate terms, you can use `$term->name` to display the name of the term and `$term->count` to retrieve the amount of posts inside that specific term.

Here is a slightly modified version of the code found in the codex. You can futher modify the output as you need

```
<?php  
$terms = get_terms('countries');

 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<li>' . $term->name . '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ')' . '</li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
 } 
?>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Traveler, here is another version of my code if you need the links to be clickable.

```
<?php 

  $terms = get_terms('countries'); 
  if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){ 
  echo '<ul>'; 

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
     $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'countries' ); 
     $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'countries' ); 

      echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ')' . '</a></li>'; 
  } 
  echo '</ul>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works great! For all who want the above code also being clickable to the link of each term, use the following code: 

<?php  
$terms = get_terms('countries');


 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'countries' );
     $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'countries' );
       echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ')' . '</a></li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
 } 
?>

Comment: Just to add a little bit more in, if you include 'hide_empty=0' just after the term 'countries', you will be able to show all the results.  So the first line will read:

 $terms = get_terms('countries', 'hide_empty=0');

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with WP Query. I haven't tested it yet, so please let me know if it works.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'taxonomy' => 'term', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
$count = $query->post_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now but try getting all the terms for "countries" and then loop through them and get the wp_count_terms for each of them.

```
    $terms = get_terms("countries"); 
    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>"; 
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
     $args = array( 'slug' => $term->slug, ); 
     echo "<li>" . $term->name . "(" . wp_count_terms('countries', $args) . ")</li>";
    } 
    echo "</ul>"; }
```

Comment: This was the solution, thanks. It would just help to share the source of this code (Wordpress Codex) like in the answer  below.

Comment: @Traveler  :  If this is the solution, please mark it as such.  

The references are:  
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
and
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms