# Show post count number assigned to custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a villa rental website, I have two custom post types named "Villa" (used to show villas) and "Destination".
I have installed the [CPT-onomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-onomies/) plugin and I use the "Destination" as custom taxonomy for the `villas` post type.

I want on each Destination post (ex. the post showing Greece as destination) to show the number of Villas (posts) assigned to that Destination (custom post type).

I have read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147718/display-the-number-of-published-posts-for-each-custom-taxonomy-term) post but this code is only showing a list of all taxonomies and next to it a number showing the post count.

This is the code showing all the taxonomies and post count.

```
$terms = get_terms('countries'); 
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){ 
  echo '<ul>'; 

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'countries' ); 
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'countries' ); 

    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name .     '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ')' . '</a></li>'; 
  } 
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry but English is not my native language I tried to describe my problem best possible.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally usage of `get_term()` or `get_term_by()` is pretty much clear cut. See the basic example below:

```
// ID is needed
$term_by_id = get_term( 12345, 'destination' );
echo $term_by_id->count;
// Or if you e.g. want use the name (or slug or id or term_taxonomy_id)
$term_by_name = get_term_by( 'name', 'greece', 'destination' );
echo $term_by_name->count;
```

Note: I said normally, because I don't know anything about the plugin you are using.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, instead of 'greece' can I add something like <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> to auto get the title?
Thank you.

Comment: You could do `$title = get_the_title();` and then `$term_by_name = get_term_by( 'name', $title, 'destination' );`. If that works with the plugin. @BigDropGR

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe the way the plugin registers the custom post type is the problem.
I should find a way to register the custom post type "destination" as a custom taxonomy, from the code and not with the plugin. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at [cpt-onomies documentation](http://wpdreamer.com/plugins/cpt-onomies/documentation/), it seems to be pretty good. For `get_term_by()` you will see the [class method has to be used](http://wpdreamer.com/plugins/cpt-onomies/documentation/get_term_by/). @BigDropGR